# Preselecting a drop down list

Tags: c#, html, knockout.js

I want to make a view in form of a list. Each row in this list consists of a name and 2 drop-down lists.
I get a list from my back end, that contains the data for that. Each row has  a value for preselecting one of the drop-downs and disabling the other.
This is the object which the list is filled with:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public IList<Selector> first { get; set; }
public IList<Selector> second{ get; set; }

public string selectedFirst { get; set; }
public string selectedSecond { get; set; }

public bool firstEnabled { get; set; } = true;
public bool secondEnabled { get; set; } = true;
```

I map the list  to my frontend into a ko.observableArray() and managed to disable in case one is preselected:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(ko.toJSON(
        @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.PostData.targetList))),
        {},
        vm.target);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.target(), function (item) {
      if (item.selectedFirst() != null) {
        item.secondEnabled(false);
      }
      if (item.selectedSecond() != null) {
        item.firstEnabled(false);
      }
    });
 });
```

And thats in my view:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tbody>    
    <!-- ko foreach: target -->
      <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span> </td><td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control"
              data-bind="enable: firstEnabled, options: first, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedFirst">
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" data-bind="enable: secondEnabled, options: second, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedSecond"></select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, all that's left is the preselecting. And I've been stuck with that for a bit now...
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to precisely cover your case, but you have a few mistakes at first glance.

- You misuse the `value` binding. The `value` binding should receive the observable to which your select is bound. So in your case it should be `selectedFirst` and `selectedSecond` respectively.
- If you need to specify the member name which represents the *value* of each option (I guess `id` in your case), use the `optionsValue` binding.

Applying these changes, your code should look something like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" data-bind="enable: secondEnabled, options: second, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedSecond"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: true, that was one of my mistakes. thanks. but it still doesn't work. plus, now the enabeling doesn't work anymore either...

Comment: Please put together a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue if you can, that would greatly help us helping you.

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to simulate the data from my backend in jsfiddle.